# IsarError: Could not initialize IsarCore library in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-isar

I got errors when running a Flutter app on Samsung Galaxy A13 in release mode. These errors are below

```
E/flutter ( 2872): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: IsarError: Could not initialize IsarCore library. If you create a Flutter app, make sure to add isar_flutter_libs to your dependencies: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'libisar.so': dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by "/data/app/~~MWoZ8e2NRqvMRsn3c8chog==/com.ljsharp.gsl_distionary-tHMfXCp9HpRkL7zf7Ueycw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libisar.so"...
E/flutter ( 2872): #0      initializeIsarCore (package:isar/src/native/isar_core.dart:74)
package:isar/…/native/isar_core.dart:1
E/flutter ( 2872): #1      openIsar (package:isar/src/native/open.dart:52)
package:isar/…/native/open.dart:1
E/flutter ( 2872): #2      _IsarNative.open (package:isar/src/native/isar_native.dart:99)
package:isar/…/native/isar_native.dart:1
E/flutter ( 2872): #3      Isar.open (package:isar/src/isar.dart:82)
package:isar/src/isar.dart:1
E/flutter ( 2872): #4      IsarDB.create (package:gsl_distionary/db/isar_db.dart:14)
package:gsl_distionary/db/isar_db.dart:1
E/flutter ( 2872): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2872): #5      main (package:gsl_distionary/main.dart:14)
package:gsl_distionary/main.dart:1
E/flutter ( 2872): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2872):
Application finished
```

Please what can I do to fix these errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add isar_flutter_libs to your dependencies?

Comment: Some other solutions can be seen here: https://github.com/isar/isar/issues/330

Comment: @Paulo Yes I did but I switched to Objectbox. Thanks though